# how to make my slider has responsive height

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, responsive

hello guys have been trying to make this slider has responsive height so it can fix perfectly on mobile but quite cant get it maybe you can help me here is my html

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">

<img src="images/slider3.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">LET'S CAPTURE YOUR HAPPIEST MOMENTS</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

<img src="images/slider4.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="text">EXPRESS YOURSELF!</div>
</div>

</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot"></span> 
<span class="dot"></span> 
<span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
```

and the css

```
    .mySlides {display: none;
}
img {vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;

}
```

the javascript

```
    var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

please help me am going crazy i have tried editing the css by adding height:auto; to mySlides didnt work thanks

Comment: your container should have certain height sizes , sldies inside it should have `height:100%` , change your container height in media queries

Comment: Welcome! You must use media queries for the responsiveness.

Comment: thanks guys for your answers they have been very hopeful id like to know which media query can i use for responsive height thank you

Answer (score 0):

.slideshow-container{
width:50vw;
height:50vh
}

//vw and vh stretch with respect to screen size
//you can set limit of vw and vh as per you need

Comment: If its really works for then please vote up for me .happy coding